# Why doesn't Chrome recognize my progressive web app?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I made a progressive web app with a nodejs backend. When I deploy it on my server, chrome does not recognize the app as a PWA. All other browsers do (firefox, opera...). This means I don't get the "download" prompt or the full screen view of my app.

It was working perfectly when it was deployed on heroku. I bought hosting and now it doesn't work. The main difference is that the app now runs on port 8443 because port 433 is used by a webserver. I looked on google and found that chrome only recognizes PWAs if they run on port 433. I asked the helpdesk and they told me to use a .htaccess file. I have not worked with one before and it does not seem to fix my problem. It automatically redirects to port 8443 but Chrome still does not recognize it as a PWA. This is the .htaccess I use:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^(.*)" PORT=8443

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# CORS
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

# HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# PORT
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^%{ENV:PORT}$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:%{ENV:PORT}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# RPROXY
# RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:${ENV:PORT}/$1 [P]
```

I was wondering if the problem really occurs because the app runs on 8443 or if there is something else I don't know.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but maybe using vhost and reverse proxy, so you can still serve your app on port 433 but reverse proxy the requests to your node server running on a different port.